# MudSlider with onmousemove

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

## Example

The following code:

```
@code {
    decimal abc = 0;
    decimal bcd = 0;

    void AbcChanged(object val)
    {
        bcd = abc;
    }
}

abc: @abc
bcd: @bcd

<MudSlider @bind-Value="@abc" onmousemove="@AbcChanged"></MudSlider>
```

results in a setup that looks like this:

[image]

As you drag the slider, `abc` and `bcd` are updated.

## Issue

If you drag the slider very quickly a bunch of times, sometimes `bcd` does not equal `abc`.

I.e.

[image]

## Question

What's a good way to ensure that `bcd` is always in sync with `abc`?

## Live example

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOmmOVdbqXnHASxU

## Update - setting `onmousemove` and `onchange`

If I set both `onmousemove` and `onchange`:

```
<MudSlider @bind-Value="@abc" onmousemove="@AbcChanged" onchange="@AbcChanged"></MudSlider>
```

things improve a bit. When I release the mouse button, `bcd` is set to `abc`.

However, while holding the button down and dragging, it's still possible to get them out of sync:

[image]

Updated fiddle:

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wawcOBxFhbOcPacd

## Update 2

I've worked around the issue in a way that's not quite related to the question here.

So the answer to this one isn't required. I'll leave the question up however in case someone finds the issue interesting.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```cs
@code {
    private decimal ABC {
        get => abc;
        set {
            abc=value;
            bcd=value;
        }
    }


    private decimal abc {get;set;} = 0;
    private decimal bcd {get;set;} = 0;
    
}

abc: @abc
bcd: @bcd

<MudSlider @bind-Value="@ABC"  ></MudSlider>
```